# Spotify Authentication in javascript?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm currently building an app for a band that would like to provide bonus content for people with a spotify premium account.

Does the Spotify api currently provide a way to authenticate and get user info, eg. their account status (free/premium)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Spotify WebAPI](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/)

```
The Web API may be used to explore Spotify’s music catalogue. 
Please refer to the following instructions.

Services

These are the available services.

    lookup
    search
```

So the answer is: NO, you cannot. Please contact them for further info.

Answer (score 0):

What Snake Eyes answered is correct. With the Spotify Web API, you can not get that information.

However, since you said you are writing an app and you mention javascript, I am guessing you are using the Spotify Apps API documented here:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/

Sorry, you still can't get that information, but if you could, it would be probably an attribute of models~Session:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/a5a59ca068.html

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is marked as solved, but things have changed with time:

New [session Class from 1.0 API](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-session.html) now gives this information:

The "product" properties gives

> The currently logged in user's account product, e.g.,
>   "premium"/"daypass"/"free".

Answer (score 0):

As an update for anybody looking at this post in 2019:

You can now retrieve lots of user information about personal data for *authenticated users*. You can generate an auth token and use this to access private data about a user's information with their permission.

More details about Spotify's API can be found here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/